# Taking value of previous row away from current row in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have a data frame formatted like so:

| GameId | Eval |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.00 |
| 1 | 1.50 |
| 1 | 0.50 |
| 2 | -1.00 |
| 2 | 2.00 |
| 2 | 1.00 |
| 3 | 1.50 |
| 3 | -0.50 |

I would like a new column which accounts for differences between the current row and the previous, but resets at the start of the next GameId so that it looks like so:

| GameId | Eval | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.00 | NA |
| 1 | 1.50 | 0.50 |
| 1 | 0.50 | -1.00 |
| 2 | -1.00 | NA |
| 2 | 2.00 | 3.00 |
| 2 | 1.00 | -2.00 |
| 3 | 1.50 | NA |
| 3 | -0.50 | -2.00 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R you might do :

```r
data <- data.frame(
      GameId = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L),
        Eval = c(1, 1.5, 0.5, -1, 2, 1, 1.5, -0.5)
)

data$Diff <- with(data, ave(Eval, GameId, FUN = function(x) c(NA, diff(x))))
data
#>   GameId Eval Diff
#> 1      1  1.0   NA
#> 2      1  1.5  0.5
#> 3      1  0.5 -1.0
#> 4      2 -1.0   NA
#> 5      2  2.0  3.0
#> 6      2  1.0 -1.0
#> 7      3  1.5   NA
#> 8      3 -0.5 -2.0
```

Or using {dplyr}

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(GameId) %>% 
  mutate(Diff = c(NA, diff(Eval))) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 8 × 3
#>   GameId  Eval  Diff
#>    <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1      1   1    NA  
#> 2      1   1.5   0.5
#> 3      1   0.5  -1  
#> 4      2  -1    NA  
#> 5      2   2     3  
#> 6      2   1    -1  
#> 7      3   1.5  NA  
#> 8      3  -0.5  -2
```